# Reprepro: associate processincoming to a component

Tags: debian, apt, repository

I am creating a corporate debian repository to simplify the process of installing custom application on servers. I am using *reprepro*.

So far i read the docs and i created a repository with one *distribution* and one *component*, importing the packages through a *processincoming* ruleset. It worked.

Now i need to create two different components in the distribution and import some packages in the component A and others in the component B.

I am missing where i can put the logic **"these packages go in the component A and these other in B"**... In the ".changes" file for every package? In the incoming ruleset? How?

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you specify where exactly an uploaded package should by placed in the `.changes` file (which, in turn, is usually populated by `dpkg-genchanges` reading it out of the `debian/changelog`).

The reason why is because the `.changes` file represents "changes to the package archive" (not "changes in the package"), so it's describing how the package archive should be modified, by placing "these package files" in "that section".

Comment: Ok, so if i understood correctly, the section field should be populated with the component name. Correct?

Comment: Actually i was unable to make it work, but i used, as a workaround, a deb-override file generated on-the-fly...